# Problemas em acessar a aplicação pelo browser

Tags: laravel, docker

Quero conseguir acessar/visualizar minhas aplicações pelo browser utilizando docker. Instalei o Docker for Windows, não fiz nenhuma configuração adicional, e criei os arquivos abaixo, junto com os seguintes testes.

Entrei no container, rodei `> php artisan serve`, resultando em:

> Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

Com a aplicação rodando, abri um outro terminal e executei o código `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000`, ele me retornou a página inicial do projeto sem problemas.

Tentei acessar via Google Chrome, localhost:8000, recebi o erro 
`This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Com o container rodando, rodei o comando `docker ps` para ver as portas, resultado: `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8000/tcp   php-api-container`

Tentei ver o ip da docker-machine, mas não existe nenhuma.

Tentei utilizar o ip do internal Virtual Switch, o erro continua.

Tentei acessar por todos os ips, que foram mostrados no ipconfig da minha maquina.

Raiz do Projeto

- /grimorie-api (Instalação basica do Laravel)
- docker-compose.yml
- php.Dockerfile

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  php-api:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    container_name: php-api-container
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
      - "8888:80"
      - "8080:8000"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
     - "./grimorie-api:/var/www/html"
```

php.Dockerfile

```
FROM php:zts-alpine3.9
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add bash

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

Rodando o comando Inspect tenho esse arquivo Json

```
{
    "Id": "a5e1bffea33aa83e9705d5c9cfe2de000c979c79c8fa8718a9e3c481d97bb77e",
    "Created": "2019-10-10T00:31:54.7573076Z",
    "Path": "docker-php-entrypoint",
    "Args": [
        "php",
        "-a"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 6090,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2019-10-10T00:31:57.1874848Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:8fb36fdc3172ae81cede1198b65d99830d30f056d4b0e3500f166d029cf9d5ba",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a5e1bffea33aa83e9705d5c9cfe2de000c979c79c8fa8718a9e3c481d97bb77e/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a5e1bffea33aa83e9705d5c9cfe2de000c979c79c8fa8718a9e3c481d97bb77e/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a5e1bffea33aa83e9705d5c9cfe2de000c979c79c8fa8718a9e3c481d97bb77e/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a5e1bffea33aa83e9705d5c9cfe2de000c979c79c8fa8718a9e3c481d97bb77e/a5e1bffea33aa83e9705d5c9cfe2de000c979c79c8fa8718a9e3c481d97bb77e-json.log",
    "Name": "/php-api-container",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "61110b176cdcbdc5f84b3d10ddd4b236f781d7e45ecdfed7603452feb17e2703",
        "d90937a8115d3b5bce051f096612548a3ded8cd773d8f574f716f3d0f55431bf"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/host_mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/Grimorie-site/grimorie-api:/var/www/html:rw"
        ],
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "grimorie-site_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8888"
                }
            ],
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8000"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": [],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Capabilities": null,
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "shareable",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/26b100adb294a905332e18963f4d088298432fffcc62144f0539585a3512b066-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/9db1246a8eba275d364a77511da820b0a36cb41ee348b2fad57d92a4990cc4ba/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a532560303cb9b2af43284da591f4da55c31035786d6b368f26a227f0f0b6473/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d92f6af3d8d4d02eb10d8b9e4c9619f8343d19bbda1cfc54517a4952a5f61a47/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f83e012fd9bbba2c732a37930babf9a9418fd85af244dc719dd4952c98f1cb03/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ceb80ca2adde5a74b9c872088fca714eedad67c737cb9568cacfbabb894976ad/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/302a758ac346f5553059dc49006f0dc78bd32d0161b0a9a200e0a16938c92d30/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5bb275316d4a2f5395bc83991126924c6a445baad5ff85734b11fb63120f3d99/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5e3ff034bc4ed73b37b4d0be7663a1dddc9b183bcf3cf85d11a8fd54fa84d703/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/04cd766ee6448c51a9baba6f2df3a11eb7983397fb59250143ff2756c8729341/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4a11363a75a829ef43f6117f1cd70ade70a0a2841cc33b46945605c1202e68f0/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/26b100adb294a905332e18963f4d088298432fffcc62144f0539585a3512b066/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/26b100adb294a905332e18963f4d088298432fffcc62144f0539585a3512b066/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/26b100adb294a905332e18963f4d088298432fffcc62144f0539585a3512b066/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/host_mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/Grimorie-site/grimorie-api",
            "Destination": "/var/www/html",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "a5e1bffea33a",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "80/tcp": {},
            "8000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": true,
        "OpenStdin": true,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "PHPIZE_DEPS=autoconf \t\tdpkg-dev dpkg \t\tfile \t\tg++ \t\tgcc \t\tlibc-dev \t\tmake \t\tpkgconf \t\tre2c",
            "PHP_INI_DIR=/usr/local/etc/php",
            "PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS=--enable-maintainer-zts --disable-cgi",
            "PHP_CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
            "PHP_CPPFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong -fpic -fpie -O2",
            "PHP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=both -pie",
            "GPG_KEYS=CBAF69F173A0FEA4B537F470D66C9593118BCCB6 F38252826ACD957EF380D39F2F7956BC5DA04B5D",
            "PHP_VERSION=7.3.10",
            "PHP_URL=https://www.php.net/get/php-7.3.10.tar.xz/from/this/mirror",
            "PHP_ASC_URL=https://www.php.net/get/php-7.3.10.tar.xz.asc/from/this/mirror",
            "PHP_SHA256=42f00a15419e05771734b7159c8d39d639b8a5a6770413adfa2615f6f923d906",
            "PHP_MD5="
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "php",
            "-a"
        ],
        "Image": "grimorie-site_php-api",
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/www/html": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/var/www/html",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-php-entrypoint"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "21f96b90be62927618278538cd112333bc092bcf0333b520d5f42647636e65c1",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "grimorie-site",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "php-api",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.1"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "cdfa0cf4147241dac3192a7d12e106fc1dc28938cd6495a6fb012db7c79f46b9",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8888"
                }
            ],
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8000"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/cdfa0cf41472",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "grimorie-site_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "php-api",
                    "a5e1bffea33a"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "1a1018c125882ea2e77294a844e75d5bbd4035c0468c5855d9d0051c5c9123aa",
                "EndpointID": "e6376ef120e65297bc3937db7730e7804741f09f0d9c4c7c8dd40dc32adc550c",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Kaue, você chegou a rodar isso em linux? Me parece uma issue do docker for windows mesmo, algo como isso https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/197

Comment: Outra coisa, ao invés de entrar no container especifica isso no teu Dockerfile, com CMD ou ENTRYPOINT...

Comment: Quando você diz Docker para windows, é o Desktop ou o toolbox?

Comment: Docker Desktop para Windows
Link: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim não testei no linux ainda, tenho que rodar o docker em um ambiente windows infelizmente.

Comment: Sei como é Kaue (:p), viu essa issue que mandei? Pode fazer o teste executando direto no ENTRYPOINT do dockerfile, e vê se algo muda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testando aqui o problema me parece ser como o `php artisan serve`. Ele não conseguiu expor corretamente a rede para o windows corretamente.

Para corrigir isso, passei o argumento `--host 0.0.0.0` para o comando e funcionou com o localhost:

[image: Navegador com localhost]

[image: saida do php artisan serve]

Mudei um pouco o docker-compose.yml para o seguinte:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  php-api:
    image: php:zts-alpine3.9 
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    working_dir: "/var/www/html"
    command: "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
     - ".:/var/www/html"
```

Como não tem nenhuma customização no `Dockerfile` consegui fazer tudo ali dentro. Repare na instrução `command`, com ela ao rodar `docker-compose up` ele vai executar `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` automaticamente para mim.

Answer (score 0):

Não tem muito sentido usar `localhost`, a rede de um "container" creio que seja a parte, então a maneira é de fato pegar o IP do container, esta [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20686101/1518921) sugere executar `docker inspect` **desta forma**:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <nome do container ou id>
```

Se for windows:

```
docker inspect -f "{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" <nome do container ou id>
```

Eu não sei se a sintaxe está correta para novas versões do Docker, porque a resposta é antiga.

Agora se não funcionar dentro do Docker você consegue executar comandos, então experimente executar simplesmente `ifconfig`, vai exibir "todas" interfaces e seus IPs, gateways, etc, provavelmente irá conseguir acessar (se não tiver nenhum bloqueio por parte do Laravel, não sei se "isto existe"), pelo seu comando `docker ps` parece que a porta externa é `8000` mesmo.

Comment: Esses 2 comandos me retornaram os ips dos containers, mas nenhum dos 2 me fez conseguir ver o Laravel pelo broser infelizmente.

Comment: @KaueAlves os comandos não são para ver, mas sim para pegar o IP do docker, chegou a pegar o IP? Tentou executar um `ping` nele?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento com o Docker for Desktop existe integração entre a rede NAT do docker com o localhost. Se estiver utilizando essa versão é possível usar o localhost sem problemas.

Comment: @gmsantos entendo, mas como não é apache e nem nginx, mas apenas "php built in server" imagino que a situação não seja configuração ou falha da parte interna "http", o que me parece que foi algum ajuste ou customização (ou falta de ajuste) no bridge, mas entendo muito pouco disto para afirmar qualquer coisa. Realmente temo que o problema seja na INFRA (no equipamento) o que faria a pergunta ser mais OFF-TOPIC ainda.

Comment: mas pode ser outra coisa também ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @gmsantos mas é justamente o que estou dizendo, infra pode ser qualquer coisa, o que provavelmente leva ao off-topic :/, a config de portar do ap também não me pareceu certa, notei sua resposta e provavelmente é o caso (podendo ser mais de um problema).